# SQL Server 2012 - Manipulate string data for stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, string, stored-procedures

Can you give me some pointers (or point in the right direction on what search terms for google)? In a stored procedure I have a parameter `@TAG` (string). I receive '(14038314,14040071)' (for example) from another application that cannot be altered. In the stored procedure, I need to split apart '(14038314,14040071)' to put quotes around each string value, rebuild it, strip out the outer quotes,strip out the parens and pass it to @TAG in the query below so that it looks like the line commented out below?

```
SELECT
    V.NAME AS VARIETY, TAGID
FROM 
    mfinv.dbo.onhand h
INNER JOIN 
    mfinv.dbo.onhand_tags t on h.onhand_id = t.onhand_id
INNER JOIN 
    mfinv.dbo.onhand_tag_details d on t.onhand_tag_id = d.onhand_tag_id
INNER JOIN 
    mfinv.dbo.FM_IC_PS_VARIETY V ON V.VARIETYIDX = d.VARIETYIDX
LEFT JOIN 
    mfinv.dbo.FM_IC_TAG TG ON TG.TAGIDX = t.TAGIDX
WHERE 
    h.onhand_id = (SELECT onhand_id FROM mfinv.dbo.onhand 
                   WHERE onhand_id = IDENT_CURRENT('mfinv.dbo.onhand'))
    AND TG.ID IN (@TAG)
   --AND TG.ID IN ('14038314','14040071')
```

Comment: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: @salmon I Posted answer can you try that??

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar I am trying to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did. Thank you all for responding. Thanks to dasblinkenlight for answering "How to replace first and last character of column in sql server?". Thanks to SQLMenace for answering "How Do I Split a Delimited String in SQL Server Without Creating a Function?".

Here's how I removed parenthesis:

```
@Tag nvarchar(256)
SET @Tag = SUBSTRING(@Tag, 2, LEN(@Tag)-2)
```

Here's how I split and rebuilt @Tag:

```
AND TG.ID in 
(

 SELECT SUBSTRING(',' + @Tag + ',', Number + 1,
  CHARINDEX(',', ',' + @Tag + ',', Number + 1) - Number -1)AS VALUE
  FROM master..spt_values
   WHERE Type = 'P'
   AND Number <= LEN(',' + @Tag + ',') - 1
  AND SUBSTRING(',' + @Tag + ',', Number, 1) = ','
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Dynamic SQL Like This

```
DECLARE @TAG Nvarchar(MAX)='14038314,14040071'
set @TAG=''''+REPLACE(@TAG,',',''',''')+''''
--select @TAG

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'
Select V.NAME AS VARIETY, TAGID
FROM mfinv.dbo.onhand h
INNER JOIN mfinv.dbo.onhand_tags t on h.onhand_id = t.onhand_id
INNER JOIN mfinv.dbo.onhand_tag_details d on t.onhand_tag_id = d.onhand_tag_id
INNER JOIN mfinv.dbo.FM_IC_PS_VARIETY V ON V.VARIETYIDX = d.VARIETYIDX
LEFT JOIN mfinv.dbo.FM_IC_TAG TG ON TG.TAGIDX = t.TAGIDX
WHERE h.onhand_id = (SELECT onhand_id FROM mfinv.dbo.onhand 
WHERE onhand_id = IDENT_CURRENT   (''mfinv.dbo.onhand''))   
AND TG.ID IN ('+@TAG+')'

PRINT @SQL
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: This is prone to sql injection. This approach is not a good one at all.